# Looking for the name of a rpg where players take on heroes from actual mythology

Tags: product-identification

The description of the game in question I saw listed Hercules as an example- but that's pretty much all I remember.

Comment: Have you tried putting "Hercules" into the search box of a site like www.drivethrurpg.com to see if that jogs your memory?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could elaborate further on what else you remember of the system. Your description could match many other systems and as of right now your question is subject to closure because of insufficient detail.

Answer (score 2):

In [Scion](http://theonyxpath.com/scion/) you play the role of one of the gods' mortal children, of which Hercules/Heracles is an archetype. It draws on several real-world mythologies and specifically includes the Greek pantheon.

Comment: It's also the most popular and publicly visible rpg of that type, so the querant is likely to have encountered it over other games with Hercules as an example, and the authors were recently advertising for a kickstarter-based new Scions system.

Answer (score 1):

There are several games that list Hercules as an example... but not consistently.

However, there's one that is actually specific to playing epic heroes: ***Hercules & Xena***, by West End Games, derived from the TV shows **Hercules: The Legendary Journeys** and **Xena: Warrior Princess**. It includes extensive examples using the shows' characters, and it includes character sheets for Hercules and Xena.